# GridView Item listing in Vertical Order

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Android Default GridView with 4 columns

[image: Android Default GridView]

This is what I am looking from GridView with 4 column.

### [image: This is what I am looking for]

Please help me, can I do this.

---

Comment: can you try with a Horizontal linear layout in portrait mode as a base layout and in it a gridview..?

Comment: You could set your order

Comment: This doesn't make a lot of sense. If there's no row limit, how can you know when to "loop back" to the top? If you wanted to infinitely scroll horizontally, THEN it would make sense. But since gridviews scroll vertically until infinity, I don't see how you could accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

**Try to use GridLayout:**

```
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"
               android:orientation="vertical"
               android:rowCount="3">

</GridLayout>
```